# SQL Server cross apply performance issue

Tags: sql-server, performance, view, cross-apply

I have a view as below:

```
CREATE VIEW V1 
AS
   SELECT 
       T1.Col1, F1.Col1, T1.Col2, T2.Col2... 
   FROM 
       T1 
   INNER JOIN 
       T2 ON T1.Col2 = T2.Col1 
   CROSS APPLY 
       UDF(T1.Col1, T2.Col2) F1
```

The inner join returns million records. Here, in this case, I know the exact value of `T1.Col1` which will be passed from the application.

Is there a way to rewrite the above view so that the cross apply can be applied to only the filtered records (based on `T1.Col1` value) instead of processing all records and then filter later? Current view doesn't return any value even after 20 minutes, whereas when I pass the values directly to the UDF, it returns the output in less than a second.

**Updated:**
Below is the structure of the UDF and I have update the question based on the comments below:

`CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF](@Col1 INT, @Col2 INT)

RETURNS @TBL TABLE(Col1 int, Col2 int, Col3 VARCHAR(10), Col4 int) AS
DECLARE CURSOR1 CURSOR FOR

SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM TBL1 WHERE Col2 = @Col1 AND Col3 = @Col2

OPEN CURSOR1

   FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR1 INTO @Col1

   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

   BEGIN 
  DECLARE CURSOR2 CURSOR FOR...
   INSERT INTO @TBLVAR 
   SELECT * FROM SRCTBL1 WHERE 
  CLOSE CURSOR2
  DEALLOCATE CURSOR2
  DECLARE CURSOR3 CURSOR FOR...
   INSERT INTO @TBLVAR 
   SELECT * FROM SRCTBL2 WHERE 
  CLOSE CURSOR3
  DEALLOCATE CURSOR3
  DECLARE CURSOR4 CURSOR FOR...
   INSERT INTO @TBLVAR
   SELECT * FROM SRCTBL3 WHERE 
  CLOSE CURSOR4
  DEALLOCATE CURSOR4
CLOSE CURSOR1
DEALLOCATE CURSOR2
   SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4`

Comment: Can u incorporate  UDF code into query

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2012/05/20/t-sql-user-defined-functions-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-part-1.aspx

Comment: If you can convert the view to an inline TVF, you will be able to pass the parameter and filter on T1.Col1. However, I'm afraid that the UDF itself is killing the performance, is there a way to inline it?

Comment: I am afraid that the UDF can't be made inline. It includes 4 cursors with a parent cursor processing 3 more inside it. Each cursor is having a complex logic. I guess, we need to rewrite the complete UDF into separate UDFs. But, again in that case, I am not sure about the performance improvement.

Comment: You seriously have 4 cursors in this thing? From the skeleton you posted it looks like you are using cursors to do inserts. Even worse it sounds like you have nested cursors. There is one and only one way to fix the performance of this. Remove those cursors and make your function set based. I would be willing to bet all those cursors can be replaced with set based logic and the performance problem will go away too.

Comment: @SeanLange Insert is common across all the cursors and two of them have condition based updates as well. Its 7 years old legacy script updated as needed and now looks like a monster facing me for the first time :). I just thought of filtering out the records returned by the join, if at all possible, so that there will be least no. of calls to the cross apply. I guess now I have to rewrite the whole thing. Just tell me one thing, if I can make each cursor inline and call them form a parent, would be performance hit severely?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your last question. If you can do this set based instead of RBAR the performance will be exponentially improved. It is always challenging taking legacy code written by somebody else and turning into something better.

Answer (score 1):

Create an inline table-valued function instead of the view:

```
create function fnx (@col1 int)
returns table 
as
return (
   select 
       t1.col1, f1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2... 
   from 
       t1 
   inner join 
       t2 on t1.col2 = t2.col1 
   cross apply 
       udf(t1.col1, t2.col2) f1
    where t1.col1 = @col1
)
```

This way you can pass the parameter to filter on t1.col1.

Comment: That isn't going to help here because the problem is that awful udf.

Comment: @sean Partially agreed, I've stated myself in the comments that the UDF is killing performance. However, it's not the same if the UDF is called a million or a thousand times. So, it is going to help to an extent.

Answer (score 0):

Use Common Table Expression:

```
 CREATE VIEW V1 
 AS
   WITH cte(cols...) AS
   (
       SELECT 
          T1.Col1, F1.Col1, T1.Col2, T2.Col2... 
       FROM  T1 
       INNER JOIN T2 
          ON T1.Col2 = T2.Col1 
       WHERE T1.col1 = ?
  ) 
  SELECT *
  FROM cte c
  CROSS APPLY UDF(c.Col1, c.Col2) F1
```

Comment: A CTE is just a cleaner way to write the query and does not affect the execution plan. i.e. there is no guarantee the UDF is only called on the filtered result set. Use a temporary table or table variable to force the result set.

Comment: and how would you pass a param into a view?

Comment: If this has to be parametrized view, of course it won't work and author should use another construct. If author knows col1 value in advance he still can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an in memory system. If you write this with java or .net. much faster results will be created.

Create a microservice to cache the results and serve them.

- Reference

Microservices , wikipedia ,

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices

Comment: We just manage the database and the application is owned by a 3rd party vendor.; For time being, we can't do this.